# How child component could control visibility of itself in the parent on child component initialization?

Tags: angular, output, angular6, behaviorsubject

There are two interchangeable child components in the parent, which visibility is governed by the parent variable **showList**

```
<div id="parent">
   <app-child-1 *ngIf="showList"></app-child-1>
   <app-child-2 *ngIf="!showList"></app-child-2>
</div>
```

**How could I control the parent variable "showList" from the child component on its initialization?**

I've tried to change it with Output and BehaviorSubject, but both this options doesn't work on initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `showList` is a property of the parent component. This means that the parent component can set its value. You want the child components to "tell" the parent component that they wish to be displayed? If so you must declare an event on the child component and listen to it with your parent component. I am guessing that there will be a control on the child component which causes the view to switch, so basically the child component requests to be hidden not shown.

**EDIT:** Since you want the child components to decide at run time which one of them is the one to display, you can't have them be hidden by `*ngIf` because then if they are hidden they are not even instantiated, and they cannot run any code which causes them to reappear. In this case you need to have them all present, but hidden from view using CSS.

The event in the child component can be declared like this:

```javascript
@Output() hideMe = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

And the listening at the parent component is done like this:

```html
<app-child-1 [class.hidden]="!showList" (hideMe)="showList=false"></app-child-1>
<app-child-2 [class.hidden]="showList" (hideMe)="showList=true"></app-child-2>
```

And the accompanying CSS:

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Then in your child component logic, when it's time to emit the event you should do:

```javascript
this.hideMe.emit();
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this option. If this.hideMe.emit(); is called during initialization it doesn't work. I mean in the ngOnInit method or in the ngAfterViewInit

Comment: You don't need to emit anything during initialization. You just need to supply a default value for the parent component variable `showList`.

Comment: Probably I didn't explain correctly. I need it during initialization. Child components are interchangeable. By the default (showList=true) in the parent component, child-component-1 is displayed. But I want to change showList property during initialization from the child-component-2 if condition is satisfied. I've tried to do in the child component 2 
ngOnInit() {
  if(condition){ this.hideMe.emit();
} But it doesn't work

Comment: I think that because the hidden component is hidden with `*ngIf` it is not even there to run its code, so it can't send any messages. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: All you have to do is to emit that output from child componant and then show\hide everytime you emit the function

Comment: @AviadP., Wow, that is amazing, I haven't had an idea that in that way it could work. I also was getting "Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'd-none: false'. Current value: 'd-none: true'." Now it works perfectly after changes are detected manually with 
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  } I had the same problem with my solution and change detector, so css-hiding method is preferable in this case.